# Как доработать кружок?

Tags: html, css

чтобы получить как на скрине ( но без использования before)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
https://jsbin.com/botoyepiwa/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можна как-то так. Хотя для продольных линей всё равно лучше использовать псевдоклассы `:before :after`

```css
body {
  background-color: #f00;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at center, #023d8d 0, #023d8d 45%, transparent 45.01%, transparent 50%, #023d8d 70.1%, #023d8d 100%);
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```